# Display MySQL records multiple times based on quantity and concatenate count

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a gift card function where customers can purchase multiple quantities of gift cards with different denominations. For example, they can buy 1 x $50 gift card and / or 3 x $100 gift cards, etc, where `3` is the `gcard_qty` and $100 gift card is the `gcard_name`. Each denomination is also linked to a `product_id`.

The shopping cart function stores each `product_id` and its `gcard_qty` as one row in a MySQL database, along with a unique code and some other data (price etc). However when I send the gift card details via email, I need ALL the gift cards to display with their own unique code. This means 3 x $100 gift cards need to be displayed three times, with an amended code, so that they can be redeemed separately.

Here is what I have so far to loop through the records and display each row:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $gcid = $row["gcard_id"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($gcid); $i++) {
        $name = $row["product_name"];
        $price = $row["product_price"];
        $cardcode = $row["gcard_id"];
        $detailsofgiftcards .= $name . " <strong>Code: " . $cardcode . "</strong><br />";
    }
}
```

On echoing `$detailsofgiftcards`, naturally I only get one unique code per gift card value as below:

> Gift Card $100.00 Value Code: 2000478282
>
> Gift Card $50.00 Value Code: 2000478283

What I want is to automatically add a dash and a digit onto the end of the unique code for each individual card and display each card as a separate product, such as:

> Gift Card $100.00 Value Code: 2000478282-1
>
> Gift Card $100.00 Value Code: 2000478282-2
>
> Gift Card $100.00 Value Code: 2000478282-3
>
> Gift Card $50.00 Value Code: 2000478283-1

If there is only one gift card of that value, display code and `-1`, otherwise display multiple records of the same row and concatenate with incremented values.

I think I need to start with something like:

```
 foreach($rows as $row) {
     for($i = 0; $i < $row['gcard_qty']; $i++) {
         // ???
     }
 }
```

And then I get completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should suffice:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["product_price"];
    $cardcode = $row["gcard_id"];
    $quantity = $row["gcard_qty"];
    for ($cid = 1; $cid <= $quantity; ++$cid) {
        $detailsofgiftcards .= 
            $name . " <strong>Code: " . $cardcode . "-$cid </strong><br />";
    }
}
```

Your inner loop was having an error. You're using `count($gcid)` where gcid is the id field. so it will always run once and terminate. Change it to quantity as I've done in the code.

Comment: THANK YOU! This worked perfectly and did exactly what I needed. The only thing missing was the opening { at the end of the top line. Such obvious logic, thanks again!

Comment: Oh I see! I've edited the version with the curly brace :)
Welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If I got you data structure naming right, then you can do:

```
$gcid = $row["gcard_id"];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($gcid); $i++) {
    $name = $row["product_name"];
    $price = $row["product_price"];
    $cardcode = $row["gcard_id"];

    $quantity = $row["gcard_qty"];
    for ($j = 1; $j <= quantity; ++$j) {
        $detailsofgiftcards .= 
            $name . " <strong>Code: " . $cardcode . "-$j </strong><br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to add new products to the database with the extra "-X" codes. Looks like other answers just help you echo all "-X", which might be more what you want...

```
foreach($rows as $row) { 
     for($end_id = 1; $end_id <= $row['gcard_qty']; $end_id++) { 
        $new_cardcode = $row['gcard_id'];
        $new_cardcode .= '-'.$end_id;

        if($end_id === 1){
            //update 'gcard_id' of the current row
        } else {
            //create a new product entry in database with all the same values as
            //$row except with the new cardcode
        }
    }
}
```

The main difference from what you had is that we're starting the for loop index on 1 instead of 0 so that we can use it in the $new_cardcode string.

Comment: Hi Josh, I didn't actually want to change anything in the database but this is good to know. I've bookmarked in case I need to use this in the future. Thanks for your help!